# Java format String while typing to German language pattern

Tags: java, javafx, unicode

Im programming something in the german language and having problems with editing texts. For example : the quotation marks in German should look like this :

> „ this is a text “

but when i type in Java, lets say in some TextArea, it will only show this :

> " this is a text "

note that my keyboard is german, and when i type in Microsoft Word, it will recognize as german quotation mark

> „“

, but not in Java or Firefox or some another text editors, like Atom. Even on stackoverflow it still shows the english quotation marks.

I want to change the automatic String formatting of JTextArea to German language, but can't seem to find a proper solution.

Comment: unicode character for this should be 8222. otherwise try to set the localization to germany. more info on that character: Unicode-Nummer: U+201E
HTML-Code: &#8222;

Comment: Not sure what kind of solution you're looking for. Word has a feature that automatically replaces standard quotation marks with language-specific ones. You can implement the same feature for your own JTextArea.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer yeah i will try that, i know the unicode for this but i dont really like typing the code anytime, this should be an user-friendly programms.

Comment: Maybe you can try setting the locale before, like: `Locale.setDefault(new Locale("de", "DE"));`

Comment: @yole Thanks, i use javaFX fyi, is it possible to implement such things in javafx ?

Comment: would be much easier to help if we knew what you want to do

Comment: @Hackerman i put the setting at main methode, doesnt seem like to work.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer yeah kinda change the setting so when i type quotation mark it should show „“ , not " "

Comment: so you want a textarea where you can type in like in word?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer exactly what i intended to say :D

Comment: i believe you can do some process on the string of the textarea afterwards but not while typing, because you only have to replace every 2nd normal " with the „

Comment: This isn't anything to do with the language/locale, but just about functionality provided by a text input control (which is not a word processor unless you program it to be so). If I type in Word,with English set as the language, it will also replace double quotes with different characters for the start and end of the quoted text: “some text” (note how the quotation marks are curved). This is because it interprets the context and knows where the start and end of the quote is. A text area will not do that unless you write the code to interpret the context and replace the characters accordingly.

Comment: You can do this by setting a TextFormatter with a filter on your TextArea, but the logic will be far from trivial.